# What are the rules used for this integral representation?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If we have $f(w)= w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\displaystyle\int_0^w \frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-z} \mathrm{d} z $, what are the rules used to form $f(w)=\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-w u} \mathrm{d} u$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $z=wu$, $\mathrm dz=w\mathrm du$...

Comment: @J.M.: how about the integral?

Comment: The function inside the integral changes from $\displaystyle\frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-z}$ to $\displaystyle\frac{w^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-wu}$. Putting all these together will do the job.

Comment: @Paul: how about $\displaystyle\int_0^w$ changes to $\displaystyle\int_0^1 $ ?

Comment: Norlyda, I suggest you read about compositions, chain rule (derivative of a composed function) and the substitution theorem (for integrals, which is connected to the chain rule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $w$, we consider $w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\displaystyle\int_0^w \frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-z} \mathrm{d} z$, which you called $f(w)$.

Let $z=wu$. Hence, if $z=w$, then $u=1$; if $z=0$, then if $z=0$, then $u=1$. Also,  $\mathrm{d} z=w\,\mathrm{d}u$. On the other hand, 
$$\frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-z}=\frac{w^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-wu}.$$
Now putting all these calculations together, we obtain
$$w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\displaystyle\int_0^w \frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-z} \mathrm{d} z=w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\int_0^1\frac{w^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-wu}\cdot w\,\mathrm{d}u=\int_0^1\frac{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-wu} \mathrm{d}u,$$
as required.